# Break randomly occurs in header on page reload

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

So I've made a website, and occasionally when the site is loaded or refreshed, a break appears between the title and the navigation menu. Does anyone know why this may be happening? The link is http://tomekc.com/rich

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: I noticed that when you get the "break", your `span` elements have no dimensions (0px) when inspecting them. Could you try setting `display: inline-block` (and also increase the navigation width) and seeing if it still happens, since `span` are displayed as inline elements by default?

Comment: Didn't got any break, loads perfectly for me, I guess it must be happening because of slow internet speed of yours as SVS said yea but I should tell you sometimes your video floats on left and sometimes it's on right

Comment: I tried setting the span element to `display: inline-block` but it did not fix the problem I was having. It would appear to be the stylesheet not loading in time so perhaps I need an output buffer of some sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was actually able to fix it by just moving my `<link>` tags higher up the page... Pretty simple fix, haha. Thanks for the help though, guys.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your bug by toggling the position on the "p" tag in your title.  But Zhihao is correct that margin & padding really do need a inline-block (or block) to render correctly.  Also the "p" tag really should not be inline, so you might want to change that tag out (or add some white-space for no-wrap if you are going to override the native display).

```
p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Now the padding might be off a little after this change but it will fix your refresh problem.  Also note that inline-block really is an ie8+ feature so if you are only targeting more modern browsers this solution is ok, but if you are targeting a larger audience (enterprise love old browsers) you probably should restructure the HTML a bit.